# How to update Table onclick button in php page

Tags: php

In track.php Page once we click on "**Submit**" button [1st row], I want to Update "**ecomexpress_awb** table -> **orderid** column" with value **123456789**....

**Track.php** page [ Based on **Orders** Table ]:

[image]

Below is Table **Orders** :

[image]

Below is Table **ecomexpress_awb**

[image]

**Track.php**

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","do_management4");

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM orders");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>order</th>
<th>payment</th>
<th>generate</th>
<th>tracking id</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$id = $row['id'];
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['order_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['payment_type'] . "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    if (empty($row['awb'])) {
        echo "<form method='post' action='call.php'>";
        echo "<input type ='hidden' name='id' value='$id'>
          <input type='submit'>
          </form>";
    }
    echo "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['awb'] . "</td>";

echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

**Call.php**

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","do_management4");

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ecomexpress_awb");

$awb_id='';
$awb_id = $_POST['awb_id'];

$sql = $con->query("update ecomexpress_awb set orderid = '' WHERE awb_id ='$awb_id'");

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: I am failing to understand what you are trying to ask :/

Comment: @B001ᛦ Thanks for reply , if i click on button in `php page` [this php page is based on `table 1` ]  , it should copy the values from `table 1 to table 2`....

Comment: What issues/errors are you facing?

Comment: @B001ᛦ i am not getting any idea what query i need to use after searching in google for hours......

Comment: If I understand you correctly you need "SELECT..." to load the data and "INSERT..." to save the data.. and "UPDATE..." to update the existing data which was inserted before

Comment: @B001ᛦ you are right, i am not getting what update query will help me : so i left blank here : `$sql = $con->query("update ecomexpress_awb set orderid = '' WHERE awb_id ='$awb_id'");`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184025/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-b001).

Comment: you're open to SQL injection and should address this immediatly

Comment: @treyBake sure, i will work on it, Thanks.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code, This may help you
You should insert awb when insert record in orders table if you have awb then you can update like this

**Track.php**

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","do_management4");

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM orders");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>order</th>
<th>payment</th>
<th>generate</th>
<th>tracking id</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$id = $row['id'];
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['order_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['payment_type'] . "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    if (empty($row['awb'])) {
        echo "<form method='post' action='call.php'>";
        echo "<input type ='hidden' name='id' value='$id'>
            <input type ='hidden' name='order_id' value='".$row['order_id']."'>
            <input type ='hidden' name='awb' value='".$row['awb']."'>
          <input type='submit'>
          </form>";
    }
    echo "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['awb'] . "</td>";

echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

**Call.php**

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","do_management4");

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ecomexpress_awb");

$awb_id='';
$awb_id = $_POST['awb_id'];

$sql = $con->query("update ecomexpress_awb set orderid = '".$order_id."' WHERE awb_id ='$awb_id'");

mysqli_close($con);


//Added code
$order_id='';
if(isset($_POST['order_id']) && $_POST['order_id']!=''){
    $order_id = $_POST['order_id'];
    $awb= $_POST['awb'];
    $sql = $con->query("update ecomexpress_awb set orderid = '".$order_id."' WHERE awb ='".$awb."'");
    mysqli_close($con);
}
//End added code

?>
```

Comment: both tables are not related to each other, is it required to related them with foreighn key ?

Comment: i think you posted track.php code two times in answer, please check and update......

Comment: As I am seeing you have two tables and both table have column awb so whenever you insert record in orders table then you have to insert awb in orders table, then you can update your ecomexpress_awb table order_id where this awb column match in ecomexpress_awb table

Comment: Please check I have added code for update in call.php and in track.php but you have to first insert awb in orders table and no need to update name of column

Comment: i got it, whenever i insert other record in `orders` table then  to insert `awb` in orders table at that time, i don't have `awb` at that time.....

Comment: please join https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184025/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-b001

Comment: Ok so in this case you should add one column in ecomexpress_awb table with name order_table_id in which whenever you insert record in orders table then you have to also insert record in ecomexpress_awb table and after you can update this by this order_table_id column

Answer (score 0):

Add one more field in your your button form in Track.php :

```
echo "<form method='post' action='call.php'>";
        echo "<input type ='hidden' name='id' value='$id'>
            <input type ='hidden' name='order_id' value='".$row['order_id']."'>
            <input type ='hidden' name='awb' value='".$row['awb']."'>
          <input type='submit'>
          </form>";
```

and then update your update query in call.php :

```
if(isset($_POST['order_id'], $_POST['awb'])
 && !empty($_POST['order_id'])
 && !empty($_POST['awb'])){
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","do_management4");
    $awb = $_POST['awb'];
    $order_id = $_POST['order_id'];
    $sql = $con->query("update ecomexpress_awb set orderid = '".$order_id."' WHERE awb ='".$awb."'");
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Comment: Why `awb` column is blank in your `orders` table? It should have some value.

Comment: once i inserted other values in `order` table, than only i need to insert `awb` column value......

Comment: so at the time of inserting row in `order` table, i din't have `awb` column values, so i kept it blank......

Comment: Ok. If you are doing the both insert at the same time, you need to update awb column in Orders table also just after you add data in `awb` table.

Comment: Just check again, you are adding data in and `Orders` table and in `awb`, so you can easily add order in `awb` table. You can use `last_insert_id` method to get order id from order table and add it to `awb` along with other awb details. hope you can understood what I am saying